# Profile methods only in main thread in Android

Tags: android, profiling

It is possible to use Method Profiling only for main thread in Android?

Now to profile methods in all threads I press "Start Method Profiling" in DDMS. Can I profile methods only in main thread?

Comment: this has some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935464/android-profiling-a-specific-thread-ui-thread-via-ddms

Comment: @herschel, I think, that only possible solution is save trace to file, remove lines with thread name not equals "main" and open in Eclipse.